# Specify DropDownList options in MVC 3 Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlistfor

I'd like to know if it is possible to assign a default value for a Dropdownlist while restricting User to select that default value from its option list.

Example :

`@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Something, new SelectList(Model.TheList), "--DefaultValue--", new { name="SomethingName", id="SomethingID", style="width:150px;"})`

Let's suppose TheList contains `{"1","2","3"}`.
When User clicks the DropDownList, he will find `"--DefaultValue--"` displayed as initial value, and also find it as one of the options available to be selected.

Is it possible only to have 1,2, and 3 alone as the options without "--DefaultValue--" ?

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to set selected value in DropDown. `--Default value--` represents `null` in selected value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Something, new SelectList(Model.TheList),new { name="SomethingName", id="SomethingID", style="width:150px;"})
```

Comment: If you do this, then it certainly won't show "--DefaultValue--" in the Options list.. but at the same time, this dropdownlist also won't have a default value. My requirement is to show "--DefaultValue--" as the initial value when the page loads, and restrict user to pick this item again from the Options list (by eliminating that item from the list).